# Discovery service issue

Tags: watson-discovery

I created a collection in Watson Discovery service it has 6 documents.4 documents include word "Printer". Then I build a query to get docs which include "Printer" word.So I got 4 documents. Then I trained mentioned 4 docs like 1 docs as relevant and other 3 are not relevant. After that I build query again. It showing 4 documents. But I think result should be 3 documents. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Relevancy training is re-ranking the documents, not removing them from your search results. This behavior will be more obvious when you have many more documents in your search results.

In addition, as a sanity check, have you verified that you indeed have a trained system? i.e. you must complete the requirements in relevancy training (if you worked through the tooling). Or if you are using the API, you can use the List collection details API call to see the training status.